# @RequestParam return null value from Postman

Tags: spring, spring-boot, api, post, postman

I am trying to make a login Restful API using Spring Boot. I am using **Postman** to test API. But When I am passing email and password through postman it returns null parameters. Because of that, my other functionalities are not working. Here is my code:

**LoginController**

```
@PostMapping("/login1")
@ResponseBody
public Response1 login(@RequestParam(name="email",required=false) String email, @RequestParam(name="password",required=false) String password) {    
        
       System.out.println("Email is:"+email);
       System.out.println("Password is:"+password);
       return lgservice.checkLogin(email, password);      
}
```

**PostMapping URL:** http://localhost:8080/login1
I am sending the following data through postman:

```
{
    "email": "Sbjain@gmail.com",
    "password": "sbj123"
    
}
```

My Expected Output is this:

```
{
    "code": 200,
    "status": "Success",
    "message": "Login Successfull!",
    "college": [
     {
       "clgId": 50,
       "name": "SB Jain",
       "email": "Sbjain@gmail.com",
       "city": "nagpur"
     }
    ]
}
```

But I am getting this:

```
{
    "code": 500,
    "status": "Failed",
    "message": "Please enter valid email and password",
    "isSuccess": false
}
```

**Logs**

```
2021-05-07 17:18:48.750  INFO 11448 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2021-05-07 17:18:48.757  INFO 11448 --- [           main] s.c.CunsultustodayWebServicesApplication : Started CunsultustodayWebServicesApplication in 4.246 seconds (JVM running for 5.143)
2021-05-07 17:18:56.665  INFO 11448 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-05-07 17:18:56.665  INFO 11448 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-05-07 17:18:56.666  INFO 11448 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
Email is:null
Password is:null
```

**If I am doing anything wrong please guide me. Thanks!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `@RequestParam` stays for *query parameters* ([@RequestParam JavaDoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html)). So, the correct usage of this API will be `POST http://localhost:8080/login1?email=test@example.com&password=pass`.

If you want to pass your parameters in *request body*, you need to use `@RequestBody` ([JavaDoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestBody.html)) and create a POJO containing your `email` and `password` fields or use a `Map` (which I don't recommend doing). Here is an example

```
// User.java
public class User {
    
    private String email;
    private String password;

    // getters, setters, constructors, etc.
}

@PostMapping("/login1")
@ResponseBody
public Response1 login(@RequestBody User user) {    
       System.out.println("Email is: " + user.getEmail());
       System.out.println("Password is: " + user.getPassword());
       return lgservice.checkLogin(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword());      
}
```

Comment: Yes, I missed that POJO class. I create it.  It worked for me, thanks. @geobreze

Answer (score 1):

using json request body you'll need a pojo

```
class LoginRequest {

public String email;
public String password;

}
```

and change controller to

```
public Response1 login(@RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {
```

Or send the login data as form params.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-send-json-parameters

Answer (score 1):

Reason: You are sending the login details as the JSON body which can be mapped using the `@RequestBody` and you are using the `@RequestParam` in which you have to pass the details as a query param. The ideal way is to create the DTO and use the the `@RequestBody`

---

When you use the `@RequestParam` you have to send the details as the query parameters

```
URL: host:port/endpoint?param1=value1&param2=value2
URL: http://localhost:8080/login1?email=Sbjain@gmail.com&password=sbj123

@PostMapping("/login1")
@ResponseBody
public Response1 login(@RequestParam(name="email",required=false) String email, @RequestParam(name="password",required=false) String password) {   
   ...
}
```

---

Currently, you are sending the details as the JSON body which can be mapped using the `@RequestBody` and you have to create the DTO to map the keys.

```
class LoginRequestDTO {
    public String email;
    public String password;
}

@PostMapping("/login1")
@ResponseBody
public Response1 login(@RequestBody LoginRequestDTO loginRequest) {   
   ...
} 

//JSON body as input
{
    "email": "Sbjain@gmail.com",
    "password": "sbj123"  
}
```

[Here](https://medium.com/@patelromil/spring-boot-annotations-b358628918ac) you may know more details on the spring boot annotations